# Prove the expansion of the first black body radiation law

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Can somebody check if I answered the following question correctly:
The first law of black body radiation is:
$U=\frac{ħ\omega}{e^\frac{ħ\omega}{KT}-1}$ $\approx$ KT-$\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$ + ... O($\frac {\hbar\omega}{KT}$), if (KT>>$\hbar\omega$) 
 where O($\frac {\hbar\omega}{KT}$) are higher order terms $\frac {\hbar\omega}{KT}$.

Prove the expansion above for KT>>$\hbar\omega$.
What I did was set x=$\frac {\hbar\omega}{KT}$ this gives U=$\frac x{e^x-1}$KT. If you then use the taylor expansion at x=0, the first term would be U(0)= $\frac 0{e^0-1}$KT which can be solved with a limit n $\rightarrow$ 0 and gives KT 
 The seond term can be solved using the quotient rule, and another limit n $\rightarrow$ 0 which gives 
-$\frac1 2$$\frac{\hbar\omega}{KT}$*KT = -$\frac{\hbar\omega}2$

Now that I have proven that the first terms are equal, have I proven that  the expansion is correct? It also bothers me that I haven't used the assumption KT>>$\hbar\omega$ in my answer. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{e^x - 1}
$$

Then

$$
f(x) = 1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^4}{720}+O\left(x^{5}\right)
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{\hbar\omega}{e^{\hbar\omega/kT}-1} =kTf\left(\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}\right) = kT\left[1 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}\right)^2 \cdots \right]
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I understand correctly the best way to do these proofs is to rewrite your equation into a form of which you already know the taylor expansion and use that in your proof. So you can't actually prove it by doing the taylor expansion step by step, like I did. Also I'm not sure how you did the expansion but I used the 
method provided in this post by Santosh Linkha https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311817/maclaurin-series-for-fracxex-1 ,does this prove the whole expansion, or just the first terms?

Comment: @Zephron If you know the expansion it is faster, otherwise, what you did is actually the way to go, just calculate $d^nf/dx^n$, for $n=0,1,\cdots$. The link provides the whole series

Comment: Ok, that cleared everything up. Thank you for answering my question.